# What does "corp." mean in the context of MLA citation?

Tags: citation, mla

From [this webpage](http://www.easybib.com/mla-format/website-citation) it has a section to enter the information about the author that is labeled "Last / corp." What is corp? Is it short for the corporation, as in the one publishing the article?

Comment: If the 'author' is a corporation (for instance, the documentation for software), its name goes here.

Comment: Suggested migration to [writers.se]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it means either enter the author's last name, *if he's a human being*, or enter the legal name of the company *if it's a corporation*.

> When a corporation or other group whose individual members are not named on the title page has authored a text, you would cite the source as follows:
>
> > **Alan Guttmacher Institute**. *State Legislative Record: 1988 Fertility-Related Bills and Laws as of December 31*. Washington, D.C.: Alan Guttmacher Institute, 1988.
> >
> > **Hunter College Women's Studies Collective**. *Women's Realities, Women's Choices*. New York: Oxford UP, 1983.
>
> The corporate author's name should appear in full, followed by a period and one space. Even if the corporate author and the publisher are the same, the corporate author's name should still appear in the author (as well as publisher) position of a bibliographic entry.

-- [*University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign*](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/citation/mla/corporate/)